# Read the end of an IP Adress

Tags: python, python-2.7, ip

I would like to get back the last part of an IP address and save it. I think it's very simple to do it but I don't know how to. So, I can read the IP address of a variable `IP_adrr`. For example, if I do a print in my code :

```
print IP_adrr
```

I get back `192.168.1.25` but I just want to get back `25`, how is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IP_adrr.split('.')[-1]`

if `IP_adrr` is not a `string` cast it to a `string` by `str(IP_adrr)`

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_last_part_of_ip_addr(ip_addr):
    if not isinstance(ip_addr, str):
        ip_addr = str(ip_addr)
    return ip_addr.split('.')[-1]


print get_last_part_of_ip_addr('192.168.1.25')
25
```

Answer (score 0):

One split from the right side is sufficient:

```
ip_addr.rsplit('.', 1)[1]
```